# Crystal reports executing system procedure

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have many reports executing from Crystal reports 10 using ODBC connection on SQL Server 2008R2 database which are consuming memory.
As per the SQL Profiler I can see when a crystal reports session executed it first executed system procedure SP_Columsn and Sp_Stored_procedure which are actually consuming memory.

I did some research and found about a report option 'verify at first refresh' and 'Verify database' which I by default checked which calls those System SP internally so I unchecked the option but still I can see system Sp executing in profiler.

Can anyone please tell me how can I avoid calling system SP from Crystal Report?

Comment: You can [`DENY EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) permission on those stored procedures, but this will likely cause other issues in Crystal Reports.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the comment. I guess reports will fail with 'execute permission is denied' if I Deny exec permission